# CakePHP Return Array From Ajax Post Call

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, cakephp

I know there are a ton of other 'duplicate' questions out there, regarding this topic. But I'm still stuck. I'm simply trying to console log an array passed from PHP through ajax.

In CakePHP 2.X:

In View:

```
<button class="quarter q1" value="1" value>Quarter 1</button>
<button class="quarter q2" value="2">Quarter 2</button>
<button class="quarter q3" value="3">Quarter 3</button>
<button class="quarter q4" value="4">Quarter 4</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.quarter').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var quarter_val = this.value;

        $.ajax({
            url: "/rep/testQueue",
            type: "post",
            data: {quarter_val:quarter_val},
            success: function(data) {
                var months = <?php echo json_encode($months); ?>;

                console.log(months);
            },
            error: function(){

            },
            complete: function() {
            }
        });

    });
  });
</script>
```

In my Controller:

```
public function queue() {
  if($this->request->isPost()) {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->layout = false;

    $quarter_chosen = $this->request->data['quarter_val'];
    $month s= $this->_get_quarter($quarter_chosen);

    $this->set('months', $months);
   }
  }


  public function _get_quarter($quarter_chosen){
      switch($quarter_chosen) {
          case 1: return array('January', 'February', 'March');
          case 2: return array('April', 'May', 'June');
          case 3: return array('July', 'August', 'September');
          case 4: return array('October', 'November', 'December');
      }
  }
```

I've tried multiple different things. array_map, JSON.parse, setting dataType to json. Still, when I try to console log months in the ajax success function, I get null.

If I'm not understanding something correctly, please fill me in, or share sources that will. Thank you kindly.

Comment: Where does that Php variable $months come from? Why you are not using the data variable in the success function?

Comment: You are accessing a PHP variable from jQuery, which doesn't know about PHP. The code you are sending from the controller is not JSON so you cannot parse it in jQuery. You cannot access a PHP member called "$months" in that page, that's not the flow. You need to handle it with jQuery, not with PHP. I suggest you read a little more about jQuery and PHP, is not so difficult and if you understand it better you will be doing better and easier.

Comment: It comes out as array() but the when I try to console log data it prints nothing.

Comment: I already told you why.

Comment: How would I go about passing the array the variable contains? Or can you provide me more specific examples of where I can practice these methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mate, you can use the cake's JS helper. On the 'succes' at the Js->request method, the data will be received as "data".

```
//somewhere on view
$this->Js->get('.quarter')->event('click', 
    'var quarter_val = $(this).val();' .
    $this->Js->request(
      array('controller' => 'ya controller', 'action' => 'ya action' , 'ya arguments (if needed)'),
      array(
          'async' => true,
          'dataExpression' => true,
          'data' => '{quarter_val: quarter_val}',
          'method' => 'POST',
          'success' => 'console.log(data);' // It should print the returned data into your console
        )
      )
);

//Now, to print the buffered script by the JS helper:
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();

//To print it into your script block
$this->append('script');
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
$this->end();
```

Your controller method should echo the array instead set it with $this->set(). You will receive the data with JS so you must echo the data json_encoded so your script can use it.

```
//On your queue method, instead $this->set('months', $months);
echo json_encode($months);
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax request is :

```
url: "/rep/testQueue",
```

and in your controller you don't have any testQueue() method. In cakePHP your ajax request url must be :

```
url: "/yourControllerName/yourMedhodName",
```

Comment: Sorry, I actually just forgot to translate that properly here. I have testQueue in my actual code, I meant to take out the word 'test' for this SO post.